# I want to use a variable in a WHERE clause in a SQL query, getting no results with this, also no errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

if I remove the 'column' parameter from the function and hard code a column name in the where clause this query works.

```
static async findByColumn(column, searchTerm) {
    const term = `%${searchTerm}%`;
    const { rows } = await pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM characters
        WHERE $1
        ILIKE $2`,
      [column, term]
    );
    if(!rows[0]) return null;
    else return rows.map(character => new Character(character));
  }
```

Comment: You cannot pass column or table names as parameters - regardless of your programming language. You need to construct the SQL dynamically using string concatenation before you run it.

Comment: ok cool thanks! Yeah I ended up just inserting it as a template literal ${column} and that worked!